# Is there an IE7 padding workaround without specifying dimensions?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a `<p>` tag with 9px of padding all around.  Looks fine in FF and IE8, but not IE7.  It "shrinks" the `<p>` tag down.  This becomes obvious to the viewer as the `<p>` tag has a semi-transparent PNG used for the background and you can see it doesn't touch the right side of the containing `<div>` like it does in the other 2 browsers.

Without getting into the "why", my question is simply this: is there a way to get the `<p>` tag with the 9px of padding to fill the available space in IE7 without having to specify a width (pixel or percentage)?

Thanks!

Sample HTML code:

```
<a href="#">
    <img class="off" src="image1.png" />
    <img class="on" src="image2.png" />
    <p>Some copy.</p>
</a>
```

Sample CSS code:

```
a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

a img.on {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
}

a:hover img.on, a:hover p {
    visibility: visible;
}

a p {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: url(bg.png) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code? or a link?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really help me as it doesn't really illustrate the problem. Try setting the width and height of your p to be 100%. You might find that makes it slightly too large, in which case you'll need to set the width and height for IE6/7 to be the direct pixel size height and width minus the padding values (x2 as its both sides).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because the 2nd image is larger than the first, setting the `<p>` to 100% in width does make it too long.

I created a solution in JQuery that solved the problem dynamically.  It sets the `<p>` width by getting the padding-top value from it (defined in CSS), multiplying it by 2, and then subtracting it from the width of the first image (.off).  This seemed to be a more elegant way to do it as you can update the padding in CSS without having to update the JQuery code and you don't have to put static width info into the CSS file.  This appears to be working in all browsers.